# Asp.net web api with queue for storing event logs in database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, message-queue

I have several JavaScript based web application running. Each application creates usage event logs (logging various click events). I want to log all these events in a SQL database using asp.net web api.

Here are the key points to consider:

1. Each message will have 4-5 properties (name, eventType, appId, payload, userId). The payload is a JSON format object. This will allow me to store any object in database in string format
2. I am expecting users to send 1000-1500 messages per minute at peak load.
3. I am thinking once end point receives a message, I will put the message in queue & then store the message in MSSQL DB.

Here are my questions:

1. Does it makes sense to queue message on client side and then send the events in batches on 20 messages or after every 3 minutes. This will save extra load on network and web api.
2. Considering the message size & no of messages that can come per minute, Does it makes sense to use in memory queue in this case? I want a really fast queue & want to avoid dependency on third party queue solutions. There is NO requirement to maintain the sequence of messages.
3. I understand that if we restart the web server, I can loose messages which is fine considering we have a up time of 99%.
4. Do I need multiple consumer (all doing same thing, writing data to a table) or just a single consumer.
5. Is there any way to keep the SQL connection open for some time rather then opening closing connection for each message.

Comment: You really want to store this in sql server? querying might be not so easy. How is the payload formatted? Have you considered a nosql solution? Which process will process the queue? I would do it in a separate process. Normally I would suggest using something like the Azure EventHub for things like this.

Comment: @PeterBons Funny that I thought Google Analytics instead (also event based), since his apps are all in Javascript anyway. Each event label could have the following format "Time: User String (sanitized)". There's an issue though, some adblockers block Google Analytics entirely.

Comment: @CPHPython other option could be applications insights , an azure service. Has a free tier as well. Anyway, lots of option. Too bad when there are restrictions when it comes to 3rd parties. a do-it-yourself option might be reinventing the wheel. And when scalability is an issue.......

Comment: @PeterBons: the payload is a JSON format object. This will allow me to store any object in database in string format. I would love to use MongoDB (which works well for my requirement) but my organization does not support it. So either SQL server or Oracle are the only options.

Comment: @OpenStack json makes sense in sql 2016 (it has built-in support). Otherwise try converting it to xml and use the xml data type. You can index xml columns in sql server.

Comment: @PeterBons: JSON support by SQL server 2016 is very limited and has lot of restriction. Do you see any issues with storing payload as string in SQL server and then letting JavaScript front end to convert it into required format.

Comment: @OpenStack No, but I did something similair once and if you have a need to query for specific payload values you're in  trouble, since you have to load all data to parse the payload and filter on payload value.

Comment: @PeterBons: Completely agree. but this gives me flexibility to save any data without changing the structure of the database. I need this flexibility as different clients will send their application specific data to the backend and I cannot guess what that data will now at this point of time.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement it using the producer consumer pattern. There are plenty of examples on the Internet using a blocking collection. The producers are web api end points that add objects into a shared blocking collection, and the consumer is a background thread reading from the blocking collection. The key point here is that the consumer has to insert into SQL Server as fast as possible, because SQL Server is likely to be the bottleneck. Inserting one row at a time in one transaction is the worst option. It would be faster to insert rows in batches, and one transaction per batch. But the fastest option is to insert row batches using the bulk insert interface, the SqlBulkCopy class provides that interface.

To use SqlBulkCopy efficiently, you need to choose SqlBulkCopyOption.TableLock, therefore multiple consumers doesn't make sense.

You don't need to worry about reusing the connection, connection pooling exists for that purpose. When you close the connection in your c# program, the connection is not actually closed, it is returned to the pool. When you create and open a new connection, what it really happens is that one open connection is taken from the pool.

Comment: Had to do something similar in the past, averaging 9000 messages a minute, msmq load balanced across 4 queues, tlp, sql server, optimal batching for us around 20 records per batch. We had to do some processing before storing so that was the bottleneck, not sql server in our case.

Answer (score 1):

1. queue`ing on the client side - would make sense in case of the bad connection. meaning something like the mobile. Also would cause some bundles to be lost.. so NO.
2. In memory queue is fine (as long as You can allow for loss of messages). I would recomend using MSMQ, cause it's transactional and is able to process ~2K messages per SECOND, which is more than sufficient for given requirements
3. (above answer would solve the potential loss and would enable distributed transactions, coupling both operations in one transaction - i.e. removing from the queue and adding to SQL)
4. NO. SQL server is the bottleneck, not the in memory processing.
5. yes of course. don't close it at the end of the loop. (u can use a timer for closing it, or read more about connection management)

   5.1. make sure You use SQL BULK insert
   https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/

Comment: Regarding 5.1: Personally I wouldn't use entity framework in this particular situation since it comes with a (small) performance penalty.

Comment: I'm suggesting use of SQL BULK INSERT, You can script it manually if You want. Are You saying that the suggested package has a BIG overhead ? (I'm not speaking about EF, but about this particular package)

Comment: ah my bad, since it was a package for EF I assumed you meant to use EF combined with that package instead of using just ado.net with sql bulk insert.